# Match when there is dash with spaces before and after

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match only when there is a dash detected with spaces before and after. For example:

```
"first - place"
```

I would also need an separate example when there is dash detected with just one space and no space after, for example:

```
"first -place"
```

Comment: `/[a-zA-Z]+\s?-\s?[a-zA-Z]+/`

Comment: You can use `.* - .*` for first and `.* -(?:\S.*|$)` for second

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `/( - )+/g` and `/( -)+/g`.

This generator should help you : https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Both side space-

```
var str = "first - place";
var patt = new RegExp(/\s-\s/);
var res = patt.test(str);
```

Before space-

```
var str = ""first -place" ";
var patt = new RegExp(/\s-/);
var res = patt.test(str);
```